# Let method failing to generate variable correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

The let method should be creating a bills1 variable for each example with a name of 'Bills 1'. Instead, I get an error:

```
  1) BillsHelper should be valid
 Failure/Error: @bills1.name should eq('Bills 1')

   expected: "Bills 1"
        got: BillsHelper

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -"Bills 1"
   +BillsHelper
 # ./spec/helpers/bills_helper_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And my helper test:

```
describe BillsHelper do
let(:bills1) { Bill.create(name: 'Bills 1', amount: 1.00) }

it "should be valid" do
    @bills1.name should eq('Bills 1')
end

it "#bill_total" do
    expect(bill_total).to eq(2.00)
end 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `bills1` in your `let` block, but you're accessing `@bills1` in your `it` block. Further, you've accessed the implicit `subject` with your `should` invocation. While `RSpec` has suggested migrating to the new `expect` syntax, if you want to use `should`, it's a method on the object you're evaluating (e.g. `bills1.name.should` instead of `bills1.name should`).

Answer (score 1):

Defining things in a `let` block like that will create them for your test in a local scope, ie. `bills1` not `@bills1`.